# Solving $\sin(x)=\cos(2x)$

Tags: trigonometry

Please write a step by step solution and if possible an explanation. Thanks!

All I did so far is:

$\sin(x)=\cos(2x)$

$\sin(x) - \cos(2x) = 0$

Don't know where to go from here...

Comment: Hint: $\cos(2x)=1-2\sin^2(x)$.

Comment: I manage to solve it after your hint, but can you explain why is your formula correct?

Comment: @Gruja do you know the formula $$\cos(A+B)=\cos A\cos B-\sin A\sin B$$? That's where that comes from. (And using $\cos^2 x+\sin^2 x=1$)

Comment: Okay, using the first formula we get:

$cos(x + x) = cos^2x + sin^2x$

...and that equals 1. How did @Jean-ClaudeArbaut get $1 - 2sin^2x$?

Comment: As in your previous equation, there are many different methods to resolve, an elementary way described below by lab bhattacharjee. Others using formuales for double angles of factorization of sum (or difference in this case).

Comment: Please look at Noor Aslam's solution it's the easiest to understand. You miswrote the cosine addition formula. cos(x+x) = cos^2x - sin^2x not cos^2x + sin^2x. the cosine addition formula is cos(A+B) = cosAcosB - sinAsinB. Replacing B with -B gives you cos(A-B) = cosAcosB + sinAsinB. Note the change in signs for cosine addition formula. Since cos^2x + sin^2x = 1, then cos^2x = 1 - sin^2x. So cos2x = (1-sin^2x) - sin^2x = 1 - 2sin^2x

Comment: No, $\cos(x+x)=\cos^2x\color{red}{-}\sin^2x$. And of course $\cos^2x\color{red}{+}\sin^2x=1$. Now eliminate $\cos^2x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\cos x=\sin(90^\circ-x)$$

$$\sin y=\cos(?-y)$$

Now use $$\cos C=\cos D$$ or $$\sin C=\sin D$$ from 
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Comment: In fact no factorization formulae needed, just use the properties of sin and cos functions, parity and/or  periods.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from your last equation:

$\sin x - \sin (\frac{\pi}{2}-2x) = 0$

Now you know how to continue.

Comment: Much better than my hint, +1

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut , thx, get 500 now ☺️

Answer (score 1):

We can solve the trigonometric equation as also:
$$\sin x=\cos 2x$$
$$ \Rightarrow ~ \sin x=1-2\sin^2 x$$
$$\Rightarrow ~ 2\sin^2 x + \sin x -1=0$$
Now try to transform the the above trigonometric equation in polynomial form as:

Let $t=\sin x$ then above final equation becomes
$$2t^2+t-1=0.$$
Solving this we get that 
$$t=\frac{1}{2},-1.$$ Now we know that $t=\sin x$, when $t=\frac{1}{2}$, then $\sin x=\frac{1}{2}$, which implies that $x=\sin^{-1}(\frac{1}{2})=\pi/6$ and when $t=-1$, then $\sin x=-1$, which implies that $x=\sin^{-1}(-1)=-\pi/2$.